# Python_Cookbook_3rd_Edition 6.12 a Question

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookbook

Python_Cookbook_3rd_Edition

6.12. Reading Nested and Variable-Sized Binary
Structures

```
import struct
import itertools

def write_polys(filename, polys):
    # Determine bounding box
    flattened = list(itertools.chain(*polys))
    min_x = min(x for x, y in flattened)
    max_x = max(x for x, y in flattened)
    min_y = min(y for x, y in flattened)
    max_y = max(y for x, y in flattened)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(struct.pack('<iddddi', 0x1234,
                            min_x, min_y,
                            max_x, max_y,
                            len(polys)))
        for poly in polys:
            size = len(poly) * struct.calcsize('<dd')
            f.write(struct.pack('<i', size + 4))
            for pt in poly:
                f.write(struct.pack('<dd', *pt))
```

Why use `f.write(struct.pack('<i', size + 4)) size+4`？

I think just `f.write(struct.pack('<i', size))`is ok

Comment: Please share what is the objective, sharing the question is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

In the book in the figure right before the code, it shows how polygon records are encoded. The first field is an `int` whose value is "Record length including length (N bytes)". Since this record length is written as a 4-byte `i` integer, `4` is being added to `size` of all the points (pairs of X,Y coordinates) comprising the polygon.

Comment: but if i change the code to " f.write(struct.pack('<i', size))" , the result is still ok.

Comment: That's because the code in the `read_polys()` function that almost immediately follows `write_polys()` divides the length value read, `pbytes`, by `16` when it's read back, so you're right about it not mattering. However, there's another `read_polys()` function presented later on (page 212) in the same section which makes use of a class method utility named `SizedRecord.from_file()` to read polygons, and it has the keyword argument `includes_size=True`. That function reads the data in a different manner and in a way where whether the `+ 4` was used or not could matter.